# How to read terminal output of nc utility?

Tags: python, bash

I need to run a command like

```
nc 123.123.123.123 1111
```

in Bash. The service I'm connecting to will send occasional messages and expect a response in the terminal. After hitting enter, it will send another prompt and expect another response.

I want to automate this in Python, but I don't know how to read the output of the nc command. I need to continually re-read from the terminal after submitting the previous reply.

Is there an easy way to point Python at a specific terminal and say "get the contents of this"?

Comment: You can use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module and connect the process' `stdout` to a pipe that your python script can read.

Comment: Sounds like you need to implement a TCP client? It's not really about the terminal, is it?

Comment: Since you want output similar to `nc`, you can consider using python `sockets`.

Comment: I've been trying to use subprocess but it looks like that module waits until the command is done before letting the rest of the python script execute. I need it to keep running so it can actively take new outputs from the terminal as the nc command runs, and then process them in the python script.

Answer (score 0):

You can open `nc` from python in subprocess and pipe stdin, stdout and stderr.
I've put together example, which will read from `nc` server and consume messages. Just for demonstration I've added some primitive protocol handling. When `b"OK\n"` is received, our client respond with `b"Got it!\n"`. When `b"EXIT\n"` is received, client close.

Please make sure to run Your `nc` server with `-k` parameter, to keep server alive after client closes connection.

```
nc -lk 123.123.123.123 1111
```

Here is full example:

```
import subprocess

# Open new subprocess and run nc in a shell, pipe stdin, stdout and stderr
proc = subprocess.Popen(["nc 123.123.123.123 1111"], shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
    response = proc.stdout.readline()
    if response == b"OK\n":
        # Write back to the process
        proc.stdin.write(b"Got it!\n")
        proc.stdin.flush()
    elif response == b"EXIT\n":
        print("Client is closing")
        break
    else:
        print(response)

# Terminate process
proc.terminate()
```